# Are magical exchange programmes possible in the Wizarding World?

Tags: harry-potter

Would it be possible that someone from Ilvermorny comes to study at Hogwarts or vice versa? Like an exchange program?

Comment: Please contact the headmaster for further details.

Comment: The other question asks for permanent transfer which we don't know if can happen. This one asked for exchange programmes that we know exist (see my answer in the question marked as duplicate)

Comment: @Ram So you are saying that the answer to this question can be found in the answers to the duplicate questions.

Comment: @Blackwood I recently answered the question just because I notice this one here marked as duplicate. I'm saying this one is the best question, the other question couldn't be answered (just partially). In fact if it hadn't been close I would have answered this one and the other would be the duplicate.